# Vue2 create component based on data

Tags: vuejs2, vue-dynamic-components, async-components

I want to create a component based on ajax api response or data which include:

1. template
2. data
3. methods - there may be several methods

Remark: response or data is dynamic and it is not saved in file.

I have tried to generate and return result like :

```
<script>
        Vue.component('test-component14', {
            template: '<div><input type="button" v-on:click="changeName" value="Click me 14" /><h1>{{msg}}</h1></div>',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    msg: "Test Componet 14 "
                }
            },
            methods: {
                changeName: function () {
                    this.msg = "mouse clicked 14";
                },
            }
        });

</script>
```

and do compile above code :

```
axios.get("/api/GetResult")
    .then(response => {
        comp1 = response.data;
        const compiled = Vue.compile(comp1);
        Vue.component('result-component', compiled);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I got error on `Vue.compile(comp1)` -

> - Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as
>   <script>, as they will not be parsed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's returned by /api/GetResult ?

Comment: Return is the first part of code - `<script>
        Vue.component('test-component14', { ... </script>` that is a complete component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Api should return a JSON with every property required by a Vue component (name, data, template, methods), note that methods needs to be converted into an actual js function (check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) about that)

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      apiComponent: { template: '<div>Loading!</div>' }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadApiComponent() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.buildApiComponent(JSON.parse('{"name":"test-component14","template":"<div><input type=\\\"button\\\" v-on:click=\\\"changeName\\\" value=\\\"Click me 14\\\" /><h1>{{msg}}</h1></div>","data":{"msg":"Test Componet 14 "},"methods":[{"name":"changeName","body":"{this.msg = \\\"mouse clicked 14\\\";}"}]}'));
      }, 2000);
    },
    buildApiComponent(compObject) {
      const {
        name,
        template,
        data,
        methods
      } = compObject;

      const compiledTemplate = Vue.compile(template);

      this.apiComponent = {
        ...compiledTemplate,
        name,
        data() {
          return { ...data
          }
        },
        methods: methods.reduce((c, n) => {
          c[n.name] = new Function(n.body);
          return c;
        }, {})
      };
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadApiComponent();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component :is="apiComponent" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks good.  I'm just curious that is it possible to return Vue SFC or Vue.component script?

Comment: I think you can take a look at the [SSR mode](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) (Server side rendering)